# Unable to install Nunit on my Visual Studio 2015 Continuity Edition?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, nunit

I have installed Visual Studio 2015 Community edition update 3 on Windows 7 64 bit edition. Now Open Manage NUGet Packge. Try to install NUnit3, NUnit Test Adaptor to design NUnit Tests. Here i am able to download successfully. But those were not listed in References of the project. 
I did lot of combitions but still no luck.
Can anyone help me how to resolve the issues? Any further settings required. Please let me know.

Comment: Maybe, you installed your extension using administrators credentials and running VS as "normal" user (and vice-versa), in that case you will not see your extensions installed. Please, provide some more information, what steps you made already. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Erko, Now i am able to see Nunit packages by opening VS as administrator. Appreciate your effort.

Comment: Now issue is resolved. @Erko Please close this question.